# react tooltip fire componentDidupdate on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've a custom written react tooltip component, but when it makes my app become laggy because it accept ref and it fire componentDidUpdate many times to get the position of the node to calculate the position of the tooltip content.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { position, visible } = this.state;
    const wrapperRect = this.wrapperRef?.getBoundingClientRect();
    const contentRect = this.contentRef?.getBoundingClientRect();
    const scrollTop = window.screenTop;
    
    if (contentRect && wrapperRect) {
      const { height } = contentRect;
      const { top } = wrapperRect;
      const calculatePosition = prevProps.position || (top - scrollTop > height ? Position.TOP : Position.BOTTOM);
      if (calculatePosition !== position || visible !== prevState.visible) {
        this.setState({ position: calculatePosition });
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I optimize this? It's worse when I have few tooltip in one page.

Comment: Consider comparing `prevState.position` and `prevProps.position` with `this.state.postion` and `this.props.position` before doing anything else

Comment: @fortunee compare ```this.state.position``` and ```prevProps.visible``` will do?

Comment: Are you asking or stating a fact?  @alice_morgan

Comment: @fortunee both?

Comment: Well the idea is you don't wanna run the whole `wrapperRect` and `contentRect` etc. if the previous state/previous props are equal to the current props/state

Comment: it's enough to check if the visible is different or not right? why bother compare all the prop?